# Count the number of cells in a found column using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am pretty new to VBA and I have been fighting with creating one simple report for many days so I decided to inquire for some help. I will be really grateful for any tips you have or could point to any errors I might've made in my code.

I have the below piece of code (extracted from my loop). What I want to do is to create a list based on around 20 excel files that will have below stats:

1. name of the current tab inside the workbook
2. count of nonblanks in a column which name contains word "Difference" (always in row 7 but can be in different columns)
3. count from the same column but where cells are not blank AND different than 0.

For the last stat I didn't even start so you won't see it in my code but I would appreciate if you have any tips for this one too (which method best to use).

```
Windows("PassRate.xlsm").Activate
b = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1
Cells(b, 3) = xlWorkBook.Worksheets(i).Name
xlWorkBook.Worksheets(i).Activate
Set Myrng = Range("B7:M9999").Find(What:="Difference", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False)
If Not Myrng Is Nothing Then
RowQnt = xlWorkBook.Worksheets(i).Myrng.Offset(9999, 2).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).count
End If
Windows("PassRate.xlsm").Activate
Cells(b, 4) = RowQnt
```

My problem is that the macro runs and works, but the result I get is the list of tab names but all counts are 0 and I cannot overcome this issue. For the line number 7 I've also tried the piece of code below which yields the same result.

```
RowQnt = xlWorkBook.Cells(Rows.count, Myrng).End(xlUp)
```

Is it possible that my problem is due to the fact that in the source files the column containing word "Difference" is sometimes two merged columns? Unfortunately, I cannot change that as these are some automatically generated files from another program.

Comment: what is `xlWorkbook`?

Answer (score 0):

`xlWorkBook.Worksheets(i).Myrng` isn't a valid `Range` syntax while you can simply use `MyRng` which you already set to a not null `Range` reference and already has both parent `worksheet` and `workbook` references *inside* it

but even `Myrng.Offset(9999, 2).Cells` wouldn't do since it references one cell only and not a range of cells

you need a `Range(Range1, Range2)` syntax, where both `Range1` and `Range2` are valid `Range` references to the first and last cell of the range you actually want to count not blank cells of

furthermore you could use `WorksheetFunction.CountA()` function instead of `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)` range, since this latter errors out if no *constant* cells are found in the range it's being applied to (so you'd need a check) while the former simply returns zero if no not empty cells are found

for all what above you could write the following `GetRowQnt()` function:

```
Function GetRowQnt(sht As Worksheet) As Long
    Dim Myrng As Range

    With sht '<--| reference passed worksheet
        Set Myrng = .Rows(7).Find(What:="Difference", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False) '<--| find "Difference" in its 7th row
        If Not Myrng Is Nothing Then GetRowQnt = WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range(.Cells(8, Myrng.Column), .Cells(WorksheetFunction.Max(.Cells(.Rows.count, Myrng.Column).End(xlUp).row, 8), Myrng.Column))) '<--| count not blank cells in column where "Difference" was found from row 8 down to its last not empty cell
    End With
End Function
```

and use it in your main code as follows:

```
With Windows("PassRate.xlsm").ActiveSheet '<--| reference "PassRate.xlsm" workbook active sheet (or change 'ActiveSheet' with 'Worksheetes("yourSheetName")')
    For i = 1 To xlWorkbook.Worksheets.count '<--| loop through 'xlWorkbook' workbook worksheets
        b = .Cells(.Rows.count, 3).End(xlUp).row + 1 '<--| get "PassRate.xlsm" workbook active sheet current first empty cell in column "C"
        .Cells(b, 3) = xlWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Name
        .Cells(b, 4) = GetRowQnt(xlWorkbook.Worksheets(i))
    Next
End With
```

please note that with

```
b = .Cells(.Rows.count, 3).End(xlUp).row + 1
```

I took column "C" as the leading one to get last not empty row from, since there was no code in your post that wrote something in column "B".

But if your real code has some

```
 .Cells(b, 2) = somedata '<--| write something in column "B" current row
```

then you can go back to `b = .Cells(.Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).row + 1`

Comment: @Maja, did you get through it?